# Login hours got ovewritten by changeset profile settings

Tags: profile, change-set, login

I deployed some new fields and added profiles to the changeset. The production login hours got ovewritten because of that. I add profiles to changesets all the time but never noticed this scenario until now. I looked at [this documentaion](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_perm_sets_profiles.htm&language=en_US) and they mentioned about overwriting of profile login IP ranges in traget org, but not lgoin hours. Is that a bug or am I understanding it incorrectly?
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the documentation is wrong. I started noticing this behavior a few releases ago. Possibly the documentation team hasn't been notified about this? I'd consider asking support.

Comment: Raised a case with salesforce. Waiting for their answer. But, overwriting login hours and IP ranges sounds odd to me. Does Salesforce consider that as a feature? Most of the times they will be different from sandbox. I want to create an Idea to exclude login hours and login ip ranges from changeset overwriting. My perspective could be wrong. what are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Well, see, a while ago, we (as admins) had the exact opposite problem: we had no way to delete IP ranges or login hours by deployment, because deployments with differing ranges or login hours caused all of those values to be combined. I'm pretty sure that they added this as a feature, but unfortunately, I've slacked off on reading the release notes over the past few years.

Comment: Thanks for the inforamtion. I'll refrain myself from opening the Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to salesforce customer service and they said the documentation will be updated in the next couple of days. Overwriting of both login IP ranges and login hours is the expected behaviour it seems.